# Sort datetime string in 12-hour format

Tags: text-processing, date, sort

I have a log file with contents like this:

```
11-12-2014 - 03:03:59AM lat = 41.990516; lon = -93.430704<br>
11-12-2014 - 03:05:15AM lat = 41.001546; lon = -93.443352<br>
11-12-2014 - 03:11:50AM lat = 42.039054; lon = -93.442001<br>
11-12-2014 - 12:08:03AM lat = 41.937911; lon = -93.369249<br>
11-12-2014 - 12:11:29AM lat = 41.949656; lon = -93.329133<br>
11-12-2014 - 12:23:02AM lat = 42.025385; lon = -93.347026<br>
11-12-2014 - 12:29:10AM lat = 41.033341; lon = -93.380586<br>
11-12-2014 - 12:38:08AM lat = 41.036720; lon = -93.436851<br>
11-12-2014 - 12:45:20AM lat = 41.998129; lon = -93.400943<br>
11-12-2014 - 12:53:36AM lat = 41.961489; lon = -93.414624<br>
```

How can I convert this to 24-hour time and sort it correctly?

Comment: Is that date November 12th or December 11th?

Comment: November 12. It is formatted as MM-DD-YYYY - 12HourTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -anle '
  $F[2] = Time::Piece->strptime($F[2],"%r")->strftime("%H:%M:%S");
  push @out, [$F[2]."-".join("-", reverse(split("-",$F[0]))), join(" ",@F)];
  END {
    print for map  { $_->[1] }
              sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } @out;
}' file
11-12-2014 - 00:08:03 lat = 41.937911; lon = -93.369249<br>
11-12-2014 - 00:11:29 lat = 41.949656; lon = -93.329133<br>
11-12-2014 - 00:23:02 lat = 42.025385; lon = -93.347026<br>
11-12-2014 - 00:29:10 lat = 41.033341; lon = -93.380586<br>
11-12-2014 - 00:38:08 lat = 41.036720; lon = -93.436851<br>
11-12-2014 - 00:45:20 lat = 41.998129; lon = -93.400943<br>
11-12-2014 - 00:53:36 lat = 41.961489; lon = -93.414624<br>
11-12-2014 - 03:03:59 lat = 41.990516; lon = -93.430704<br>
11-12-2014 - 03:05:15 lat = 41.001546; lon = -93.443352<br>
11-12-2014 - 03:11:50 lat = 42.039054; lon = -93.442001<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the GNU `date` command. It can take strings and print out the corresponding date:

```
$ date -d "11/11/2014 04:12:03PM"
Tue Nov 11 16:12:03 CET 2014
```

Note, however, that it does not like `DD-MM-YYY`:

```
$ date -d "11-11-2014"
date: invalid date ‘11-11-2014’
```

So, first run a `sed` on your file to replace all `-` with `/`. Then, pass that through `read` to get each field into a separate variable, convert and sort:

```
$ sed 's#-#/#g' file | while read date _ hour rest; do 
    echo "$(date -d "$date $hour" +"%F - %R:%S") $rest"
  done | sort -h
2014-11-12 - 00:08:03 lat = 41.937911; lon = /93.369249<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:11:29 lat = 41.949656; lon = /93.329133<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:23:02 lat = 42.025385; lon = /93.347026<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:29:10 lat = 41.033341; lon = /93.380586<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:38:08 lat = 41.036720; lon = /93.436851<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:45:20 lat = 41.998129; lon = /93.400943<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:53:36 lat = 41.961489; lon = /93.414624<br>
2014-11-12 - 03:03:59 lat = 41.990516; lon = /93.430704<br>
2014-11-12 - 03:05:15 lat = 41.001546; lon = /93.443352<br>
```

This will work on your example but fails if you also need to sort February (`02`) before November (`11`). So, a trick would be to print the dates as [seconds since the epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), sort on that and then remove it:

```
$ sed 's#-#/#g' file | while read date _ hour rest; do 
  printf "%s\t%s %s\n" "$(date -d "$date $hour" +"%s")" "$date - $hour" "$rest"
done | sort | cut -f 2-
11/12/2014 - 12:08:03AM lat = 41.937911; lon = /93.369249<br>
11/12/2014 - 12:11:29AM lat = 41.949656; lon = /93.329133<br>
11/12/2014 - 12:23:02AM lat = 42.025385; lon = /93.347026<br>
11/12/2014 - 12:29:10AM lat = 41.033341; lon = /93.380586<br>
11/12/2014 - 12:38:08AM lat = 41.036720; lon = /93.436851<br>
11/12/2014 - 12:45:20AM lat = 41.998129; lon = /93.400943<br>
11/12/2014 - 12:53:36AM lat = 41.961489; lon = /93.414624<br>
11/12/2014 - 03:03:59AM lat = 41.990516; lon = /93.430704<br>
11/12/2014 - 03:05:15AM lat = 41.001546; lon = /93.443352<br>
11/12/2014 - 03:11:50AM lat = 42.039054; lon = /93.442001<br>
```

Or, to print the dates in 24H format:

```
$ sed 's#-#/#g' file | while read date _ hour rest; do 
    printf "%s\t%s %s\n" "$(date -d "$date $hour" +"%s")" \ 
    "$(date -d "$date $hour" +"%F - %R:%S")" "$rest"
  done | sort | cut -f 2-
2014-11-12 - 00:08:03 lat = 41.937911; lon = /93.369249<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:11:29 lat = 41.949656; lon = /93.329133<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:23:02 lat = 42.025385; lon = /93.347026<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:29:10 lat = 41.033341; lon = /93.380586<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:38:08 lat = 41.036720; lon = /93.436851<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:45:20 lat = 41.998129; lon = /93.400943<br>
2014-11-12 - 00:53:36 lat = 41.961489; lon = /93.414624<br>
2014-11-12 - 03:03:59 lat = 41.990516; lon = /93.430704<br>
2014-11-12 - 03:05:15 lat = 41.001546; lon = /93.443352<br>
2014-11-12 - 03:11:50 lat = 42.039054; lon = /93.442001<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk` with `sort`:

```
awk '{while("date +%T -d" $3|getline x){$3=x}}1' logfile | sort -t- -n -k3 -k1 -k2
```

Lets first modify your log a little bit to have different dates:

```
11-12-2010 - 03:03:59AM lat = 41.990516; lon = -93.430704
11-12-1998 - 03:05:15AM lat = 41.001546; lon = -93.443352
11-12-2030 - 03:11:50AM lat = 42.039054; lon = -93.442001
11-12-2014 - 12:08:03AM lat = 41.937911; lon = -93.369249
11-12-2014 - 12:11:29AM lat = 41.949656; lon = -93.329133
11-11-2014 - 12:23:02AM lat = 42.025385; lon = -93.347026
11-12-2011 - 12:29:10AM lat = 41.033341; lon = -93.380586
11-12-2011 - 12:38:08AM lat = 41.036720; lon = -93.436851
10-12-2014 - 12:45:20AM lat = 41.998129; lon = -93.400943
11-12-2014 - 12:53:36AM lat = 41.961489; lon = -93.414624
```

The result would be:

```
11-12-1998 - 03:05:15 lat = 41.001546; lon = -93.443352
11-12-2010 - 03:03:59 lat = 41.990516; lon = -93.430704
11-12-2011 - 00:29:10 lat = 41.033341; lon = -93.380586
11-12-2011 - 00:38:08 lat = 41.036720; lon = -93.436851
10-12-2014 - 00:45:20 lat = 41.998129; lon = -93.400943
11-11-2014 - 00:23:02 lat = 42.025385; lon = -93.347026
11-12-2014 - 00:08:03 lat = 41.937911; lon = -93.369249
11-12-2014 - 00:11:29 lat = 41.949656; lon = -93.329133
11-12-2014 - 00:53:36 lat = 41.961489; lon = -93.414624
11-12-2030 - 03:11:50 lat = 42.039054; lon = -93.442001
```

The trick here is to use `-` as a field separator and sort first on 3rd field (year) then on first (month), then on second (day). All in sorting are numerical (`-n` option).

Answer (score 0):

With python and the `dateutil` module (`pip install dateutil`), you can do the sorting directly on the datetime objects:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
from dateutil.parser import parse

lines = []
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    d, rest = line[:24], line[24:]
    lines.append((parse(d), rest))

for x in sorted(lines):
    print x[0], x[1],
```

start with `python program.py inputfile`

This can be done without `dateutil` but the advantage of using it is that you don't have to specify the input time format, as long as it is not ambiguous.